# Dispatch actions on authentication with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, dispatch, nuxtserverinit

I have an `nuxt.js` app that a user can log in to. Whenever the user is authenticated using the `nuxt/auth` module. I want the app to fetch some data using the `nuxtServerInit`.

Currently I have this in my `nuxtServerInit`:

```
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
        if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
            await dispatch('products/getProducts')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This works well if I'm authenticated and the page is refreshed. The problem seems to be whenever I'm redirected after authentication, these actions are never called, thus not populating the `store`.

I have tried to use the `fetch` method instead, but in only works on the page with the `fetch` statement, not every page in my application. Also I don't want the http calls to be made with every page change.

Comment: do you have your own login function? if yes, you could load required data there after successful login and before you get redirected.

Comment: Thanks, @jumper85. I don't know why that never occurred to me. It works exactly as I want.